# linking dynamic .html form to .jsp

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, web-applications

i am new to advance java and trying to build a dynamic web application using eclipse. I have no idea how to link a ready-made/dynamic **.html** form with **.jsp** , although i have made a registration form in jsp but it is not looking nice.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

One way to convert an HTML file to a JSP is to open a new JSP file ( in your IDE ) and copy - paste the contents of the HTML file into it. Another way is to embed the Java code into the HTML file then change the file's extension from a .html to a .jsp.